# MySQL Correct title/proper case for more than one string in a field

Tags: mysql

I have a database which has a field titled 'address1'. If there is only 1 string in this field for a record, I am able to correct the case from eg 'PAULSTOWN' to 'Paulstown', or 'bishopslough' to 'Bishopslough'.

I have done this by creating a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION init_cap (s VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT( UPPER( SUBSTRING( s, 1, 1 ) ) , LOWER( SUBSTRING( s FROM 2 ) ) );
```

Then using:

```
UPDATE customer SET address1 = init_cap(address1);
```

To correct records.

However, this does not fully correct records that contain more than one string, eg 'dalesfort road' will only be corrected to 'Dalesfort road' and not 'Dalesfort Road'. There are also some entries with more than 2 strings.

How could I change the above function to cater for 2 or more strings? Also is that function declared correctly, or should I be using begin and end sections?

Comment: Or if there was a different and better way of achieving the same result, please anybody let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I found the answer at [artfulsoftware.com](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=122)

Now I just need to analyse the code and learn how it works!